# How to use a 9 patch drawable (.9.png) in my screen using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, image, android-jetpack-compose, nine-patch

I'm trying to use a .9.png file in Image composable as :

```
            Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.shadow_faq),
            contentDescription = "Faq card 1",
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(imgGeneral) {
                    top.linkTo(glImgGeneralTop)
                    bottom.linkTo(glImgBottom)
                    start.linkTo(glImgLeft)
                    end.linkTo(glImgRight)
                    height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                }
        )
```

But on doing this I get a render problem that says `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only VectorDrawables and rasterized asset types are supported ex. PNG, JPG`

How do I use a .9.png file with Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Starting with `1.0.0-rc02` and accompanist `0.14.0` you can use the [coil-compose](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#jetpack-compose) version:

```
Image(
    rememberImagePainter(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.xxx)),
    contentDescription = "Faq card 1",
)
```

---

**Previous deprecated answer**:
You can use the [**`DrawablePainter`**](https://google.github.io/accompanist/api/imageloading-core/imageloading-core/com.google.accompanist.imageloading/-drawable-painter/index.html) from Accompanist that returns a `Painter` which draws an Android `Drawable`.

```
Image(
    rememberDrawablePainter(drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.xxxx) ),
    contentDescription = "Faq card 1"
)
```

Comment: Any examples how to load 9.png image without coil library ?

Comment: I am able to load the image doing this, but it has the behaviour of a regular PNG, it doesn't resize as a 9-patch. Do I need to configure something else in the Image or the Modifier??

Comment: yeah, it doesn't resize as a 9-patch.

Answer (score 6):

sometimes ,we load 9.png to be a background of Views, just like the message item on your chat apps. And we could do like this:

first we load 9.png as a drawable:

```
 val bgImg = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
    LocalContext.current,
    if (isFromMe) R.drawable.chat_message_right else R.drawable.chat_message_left
)
```

second we could use Modifier#drawBehind() method to set a background :

```
Text(text = "This my message",
    modifier = Modifier
        .drawBehind {
            bgImg?.updateBounds(0, 0, size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt())
            bgImg?.draw(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas)
        }
        .padding(8.dp)
)
```

At last ,you will get the effect you want .

Answer (score 4):

I tried the accepted answer and didn't work for me...
I'm leaving my solution here just for future reference...

First, I defined this `Modifier` in order to draw the 9-patch as background (I think this is the most common scenario).

```kotlin
fun Modifier.draw9Patch(
    context: Context,
    @DrawableRes ninePatchRes: Int,
) = this.drawBehind {
    drawIntoCanvas {
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, ninePatchRes)?.let { ninePatch ->
            ninePatch.run {
                bounds = Rect(0, 0, size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt())
                draw(it.nativeCanvas)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it in a `Box` for instance...

```kotlin
@Composable
fun NinePatchImage() {
    Box(
        Modifier.draw9Patch(LocalContext.current, R.drawable.balao)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = """
                |This is a long text to stretch the balloon
                |Diego, are you happy?
                |I know you are
                |Just one line for this
                |Yes!""".trimMargin("|"),
            Modifier
                .padding(
                    top = 24.dp,
                    bottom = 24.dp,
                    start = 32.dp,
                    end = 48.dp
                )
        )
    }
}
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Comment: Did you set the size and the right contentScale?

Comment: I've set the size using Modifier. But I didn't set the contentScale...

Comment: I don't know what I've done previously... But it worked. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AndroidView and pass old good ImageView

```
AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier.xxx,
    factory = {
        ImageView(it)
    }
)
{
    it.setImageResource(R.drawable.shadow_faq)
}
```